# XNA MediaPlayer Issue

Tags: xna

I have the following code in Draw() in Game1. However, the Music only plays when I'm pressing the close button for the program. Where should I be putting MediaPlayer.Play() if not there? normS, fastS, slowS, and playing are all Song types. If you need me to clear anything up, just ask.

```
        if (stateS == "normal")
        {
            if (!MediaPlayer.Equals(playing, normS))
            {
                playing = normS;
            }

            spriteBatch.Draw(norm, pos, Color.White);
        }
        else if (stateS == "fast")
        {
            if (!MediaPlayer.Equals(playing, fastS))
            {
                playing = fastS;
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(fast, pos, Color.White);
        }
        else if (stateS == "slow")
        {
            if (!MediaPlayer.Equals(playing, slowS))
            {
                playing = slowS;
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(slow, pos, Color.White);
        }
        MediaPlayer.Play(playing);
```

Comment: How do you expect your sounds to play, and how do they actually play?

Comment: The Songs should play from the time the game starts until you exit, and they play using MediaPlayer.Play(). However, the song only plays when I'm pressing the close button, but the correct song does play

Comment: It's hard to say without the surroundind code, but it seems your `Play()` method is only run when you press a certain button. You should move it to the `Update()` method and only run when the sound is not playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you need to have the songs play out of the Draw method? Draw should be reserved for drawing things.

Like user1306322 said in the comment above, I would recommend moving the

```
MediaPlayer.Play(playing);
```

into the Update method, and wrap it in a conditional (so you dont just keep playing a new song every update, which I *think* is what is happening for you now since clicking and holding the Close Window x stops the updates. You could try this by dragging the window around as well):

```
if (!MediaPlayer.IsPlaying)
{
    MediaPlayer.Play(playing);
}
```

If necessary, you can leave the rest of the code in Draw, but most likely this whole thing should go in Update.

*edit* I just realised you may not have a conditional on this because you want to be able to change the song at any time. In that case, you should set a variable to hold your "Last Song", so you can compare it in your conditional like this:

```
if (MediaPlayer.IsPlaying == false || playing != lastPlaying)
{
    MediaPlayer.Play(playing);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for this answer. Sadly, it is still having the same issue. I have changed the code so that it only runs the code I posted earlier when you change states, and I also tried the lastPlaying with the conditional in update(), however, the same issues still arise.

Comment: If you drag the window around by the title bar, does the music start then too? Or only when you close the program?

Comment: Whenever I drag it around, so update() is still starting it every time, I guess.

Comment: Where do you set lastPlaying in your update loop? Is it the last thing, or do you maybe have it above the conditional statement? lastPlaying should be originally called in your LoadContent method, and then you should be setting it to the value of MediaPlayer.IsPlaying as the very last thing in your update (or at least after your call to MediaPlayer.Play)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it worked after I moved lastPlaying. I also had an extra MediaPlayer.Play() that messed it up. Thanks a ton!